# Three listviews in one screen

Tags: android, layout

I have an app on iPhone with cascading design like on the picture, and I'd like to port it to Android. Is there a simple and recommended way to  do this?

The section menu on the left (Section A, B,C,D) is the first that the user needs to select, then the user needs to pick a category in the middle (all, popular, pc, xbox,...), then he is presented with a list of articles for chosen category.

I could imagine doing it with three ListViews, but then the app could also listen to a swipe gesture to make the rightmost ListView "full screen", and hide the first two listviews. I could implement a swipe listener for the whole activity and set first two listviews' visibility to hidden, right?

Are my assumptions correct and would this be the right way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It could definetly work the way you explain it - if the design is good is another discussion. Personally I'm not a fan of throwing in endless amounts of data in one screen, when the space is as limited as it is on most mobile phones (I would probably do it with 3 different screens with a ListView on each)

Implementing the mentioned swipe gesture is doable and you could certainly just hide the two other ListViews with the function `setVisibility( View.GONE )`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: go for 3 seperate activities. that will increase functionality because you don't have to deal with vertical and horizontal scrolling at the same time

Answer (score 0):

1. You might want to use the new fragments API, it's specifically built for this kind of thing (and it's compatible all the way down to Android 1.6). Also, as KasperMoerch says, putting all that info on a small screen can get ugly. Using fragments will make it easier for you to gradually increase the amount of information displayed as the screen size increases.
2. I'm not sure you can just listen for a swipe gesture over an entire activity like that. I think you have to wrap the fragments in a custom view (for example an extended `LinearLayout`) and do the swipe listening there. However, achieving a finger-tracking animation (i.e. where the rightmost pane follows the finger precisely as it swipes across) is a pretty daunting task (I wouldn't really know where to begin, probably in the custom view though). The best way (I think) to do it is to make a compromise and just start an animation (right-to-left slide) when you detect a swipe. However, the simplest solution is to not animate at all.
3. You can also take into consideration dropping the swipe gesture altogether and just providing an "expand" button.

Comment: I could listen to swipe for all of the list views, that's not a problem, and the animating the panes is an entirely different set of problems not really relevant, and I would not animate at all for the time being. I'll look into fragments API, though

Comment: I know "it's not a problem", I was just saying that you can't really implement it like that (there's no way to listen for gestures on an `Activity`). You have to write a custom `ViewGroup` (e.g. `LinearLayuot` or `RelativeLayout`) to hold your fragments and listen for swipes in its implementation. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough.